# The callback of RTK updateQueryData is not getting triggered

Tags: reactjs, redux, rtk-query

I have the following RTK Query and the mutation. On success, I need to amend the response of the mutation to the response of the Query. I use `updateQueryData()` for this, but the update doesn't work. I can say that because the dataset is still the same even though the mutation worked. If I put a `console.log()`, it won't show either. I get the correct result from the Mutation, as well as the Query. But the update doesn't work. How can I fix this?

```
const showCase = useGetShowCase({term: props.terms, id: props.id} ?? skipToken)?.data || {};

const updateShowCase = (id, data) => {
        updateShowCaseMutation({id, data})
            .then((response) => {
                api.util.updateQueryData('getShowCase', {term: props.terms, id: props.id}, (draft) => ({
                    ...draft,
                    ...response.data || {},
                }));
            })
    }
```

When I check the redux developer tools, I can see that the query cache key `getShowCase({"term": "term1", "id": 50})` is there.

*note: I'm transforming the query results into objects here and access it as an array

```
const createApiQuery = (build, queryOptions) => build.query({
    transformResponse: (response, meta, arg) => toObject(response.data, queryOptions),
    ...queryOptions,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just missed the `dispatch`. It is clearly mentioned in the documentation https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#updatequerydata

So I imported the `useDispatch from 'react-redx'` and used the updateQueryData as follows, and it worked!

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();

dispatch(api.util.updateQueryData('getShowCase', {term: props.terms, id: props.id}, (draft) => ({
                    ...draft,
                    ...response.data || {},
                })));
```